# Приоритеты унарных операторов

Tags: java, математика

Наткнулся вот на такой пример, и расписал примерно, как я понимаю вычисления джава машины. Я понимаю, что использовать подобное в коде это ужасно, но тем не менее, решая различные тесты для собеседования, подобные вопросы часто попадаются мне. Я буду очень благодарен человеку который пояснит мне, правильно ли я рассуждаю.

```
    public class DeleteThis {

    static int a = 1111;

    static {
        a = a-- - --a;
        // 1111 = (1111 - (отложенный 1)) - 1111
        //                 1110             1109

        // a    = 1111 - 1109 ???

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);

        // 2
    }
}
```

Т.е несмотря на то, что мы имеем более приоритетный предекремент, своё (a) значение он уменьшает будучи вторым. При этом, первое всё ещё не учитывается в вычислении.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтоб разобраться, как это работает нам нужны эти правила из спецификации языка:

[15.17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

[15.7.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) Evaluate Operands before Operation

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

[15.14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) Postfix Decrement Operator --

> At run time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes abruptly, then the postfix increment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no incrementation occurs. Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable

[15.26.1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) Simple Assignment Operator =

Тут я сократил, только до необходимого минимума (в основном упустил описание поведения при ошибках - для нашего примера это неактуально)

> Otherwise, three steps are required:

> First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. ...

> ... the right-hand operand is evaluated.

> ... the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable ... and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

Для того, чтоб вычислить значение выражения `a = a-- - --a`, которое эквивалентно `a = ((a--) - (--a))` и является присвоением, согласно 15.26.1 нужно

1. вычислить левый аргумент. Тут никакого вычисления, у нас просто имя переменной.
2. вычислить значение правого аргумента (об этом дальше)
3. присвоить значения из 2 в переменную из 1

Для вычисления выражения `(a--) - (--a)` согласно 15.7.2 нужно вычислить аргументы. Причем согласно 15.17.1 их нужно вычислять слева направо. Таким образом сначала вычисляется `a--`.

Вычисление `a--` согласно 15.14.3 происходит так, что значением выражения (т.е. первым аргументом для операции `-` в нашем случае будет изначальное значения переменной `a`, т.е. `1111`), но в процессе вычисления выражения, переменной `a` будет присвоено новое значение, а именно `1110`. Обратите внимание, что это присвоение происходит в процессе вычисления выражения `a--`, т.е. до того как будет происходить вычисление второго аргумента для вычитания.

Далее вычисляется второй аргумент для операции вычитания. В этот момент переменная `a` уже равна `1110`, соответственно значением выражения `--a` (а значит и второго аргумента для вычитания) будет `1109`, и это же значение запишется в `a` в процессе вычисление выражения.

Следующий шаг, собственно вычитание (1111 - 1109) и выполнение шага 3 из операции присвоения. В результате в `a` будет записано значение `2`.

Comment: Думаю этот ответ превзошёл всё мои ожидания, огромное вам спасибо!